# Trouble Including rosbag

Tags: ros, rosbag, catkin, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am trying to follow this tutorial: http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Code%20API#cpp_api , but am running into errors with the inclusion of rosbag.  When I try to run the example code, I get a jillion lines of errors all saying something like this: undefined reference to rosbag:somethingOrOther.  However, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.  I included rosbag/bag.h and rosbag/view.h in my C++ source file, and I believe I've linked the libraries correctly in my CMakelists file:

add_executable(rosbagger src/rosbagger.cpp)
target_link_libraries(rosbagger ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

Anyone know whats going wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/116166/trouble-including-rosbag/) by [mysteriousmonkey29](https://answers.ros.org/users/9531/mysteriousmonkey29/) on ROS Answers with karma: 170 on 2014-01-08

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2014-01-08**:
open the terminal and type ($ rospack depends1 <package_name>)
in  dependencies list do you see rosbag?

**Comment by [mysteriousmonkey29](https://answers.ros.org/users/9531/mysteriousmonkey29/) on 2014-01-12**:
Thanks I tried that and it said there were no dependcies so I recreated the package (with the correct dependcies) and now it seems to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You also have to specify rosbag as a dependency of your package correctly. The first example package I found where this is done is https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl/tree/hydro-devel/pcl_ros. Have a look at the package [package.xml](https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl/blob/hydro-devel/pcl_ros/package.xml) and [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl/blob/hydro-devel/pcl_ros/CMakeLists.txt) files, search for "rosbag" and add the analogous (basically the same) lines to your package.

Also have a look at the related [catkin wiki pages](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mysteriousmonkey29](https://answers.ros.org/users/9531/mysteriousmonkey29/) on 2014-01-12**:
I have specified my dependencies as follows in the package.xml:

<build_depend>rosbag</build_depend>
<run_depend>rosbag</run_depend>

However, I am still encountering the problem (I already had these lines in there; I just forgot to include them in the question)

**Comment by [artosaari](https://answers.ros.org/users/19779/artosaari/) on 2014-07-18**:
You probably forgot to insert "rosbag" under

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
...

**Comment by [Clancy](https://answers.ros.org/users/20877/clancy/) on 2015-01-27**:
This was very helpful. I was missing the CMakeLists.txt part. Thanks!

**Comment by [resplendent star](https://answers.ros.org/users/53470/resplendent-star/) on 2021-03-12**:
hi,what need to add in  cmake?could plz be more specific?